TSQL: ORDER BY - either use a column or nothing (empty)
Currently I have the following query in TSQL:
select *
from table
order by
    col1,
    col2

But there's a condition (@cond = 1), which if it is true, then I should rather sort by column col0 DESC and then use the rest:
select *
from table
order by
    case when @cond = 1 then col0 end DESC,
    col1,
    col2

which works fine when the condition is true. But if it's false, then I have an error message (in that case I want to have the initial query).
How to make the trick here?

Ideally you wouldn't use any "tricks" here - you'd have two separate queries: one with ORDER BY col1, col2 and the other with ORDER BY col0 DESC, col1, col2  (the reason for this to ensure you always get a good execution-plan) - so is there a reason you can't do that?

if condition is true, then I want to order by col0 DESC, col1, col2, if false then col1, col2

Another approach is to move that @cond logic to a column-expression in the SELECT clause and ORDER BY using only that (though I don't know what your query-plans will end-up looking like).

What error message? The syntax you have works fine. https://dbfiddle.uk/5D-WfG2i (ignoring performance)

Because you have a difference in sort order (ASC/DESC) and the number of columns (1 vs 2) we will need to sort on 3 CASE statements.
SQL-Server example:
DECLARE @cond bit;
SET @cond = 0;

SELECT *
FROM [table]
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @cond = 1 THEN col0  END DESC, 
    CASE WHEN @cond = 0 then  col1 END,
    CASE WHEN @cond = 0 then  col2 END

SET @cond = 1;

SELECT *
FROM [table]
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @cond = 1 THEN col0  END DESC, 
    CASE WHEN @cond = 0 then  col1 END,
    CASE WHEN @cond = 0 then  col2 END

fiddle



col0
col1
col2




1
2
3


4
5
6


7
8
9






col0
col1
col2




7
8
9


4
5
6


1
2
3




It's probably best to use dynamic SQL here. That means you get a separate plan for each version of the query.
Don't forget to pass in parameters properly using sp_executesql.
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
select *
from [table]
order by';

if @cond = 1
    set @sql += N'
  col0 DESC,';

set @sql += N'
    col1,
    col2;
';

print @sql;  -- your friend

exec sp_executesql @sql;  -- add parameters here

